# Is it possible to prevent the first render and to proceed to componentDidMount?

Tags: react-native, scroll-position, flatlist

I have list with list of records. on tap of each record user will be redirected to detail page. when user comes back to the list page, list page must retain it's scroll position(i.e user should land on the same record he has tapped on). My `FlatList` is as below,

```
   <FlatList
       ref={ref => this.flatListRef = ref}
       data={equipmentsList}
       renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderEquipments(item, index)}
       keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
       onScroll={(e) => this.handleScroll(e)}
    />
```

every time user scrolls the page, scroll position is stored by using `onScroll` method to use it later

```
    onScroll={(e) => this.handleScroll(e)}
```

here is `handleScroll` method

```
     handleScroll(event) {
        this.setState({ scrollPosition: event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y });
     }
```

And here is the code to to scroll the `FlatList` to the desired position when user comes back from detail page to list page

```
    componentDidMount() {
        this.flatListRef.scrollToOffset({ offset: scrollPosition, animated: false });
    }
```

I am doing this in `componentDidMount` because, `this.flatListRef` is available until component renders at least once.

here problem is, when the first render happens `FlatList` renders without any scroll position and then when componentDidMout is called `FlatList` renders with scroll position(scrolling to desired list item).this behavior is apparently noticeable to user that rendering happens twice.

Here My doubts are,
1.Is it possible to prevent the first render so that `componentDidMount` will alone render the `FlatList`?

or

2.Is there any alternative to land the user on same scroll position when comes back from detail page to list page?

Thank You.